# how to add heading and text over an image carousel

Tags: html, image, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I want to add a heading and text in an image carousel. When it write h1 or p tags the text goes down under text. I want to keep it in middle of my image. I am using bootstrap framework.

Here is my code:

```
<section>
    <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img src="images/cover/cover-1.png" class="d-block w-100 image-fluid" alt="...">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="images/cover/cover-2.jpg" class="d-block w-100 h-auto image-fluid" alt="...">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="images/cover/cover-3.jpg" class="d-block w-100 image-fluid" alt="...">
          </div>
        </div>
        <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
        </button>
        <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
        </button>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the bootstrap documentation for captions on carousel here - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/#with-captions

If you want to place the text in middle of the image, change/add the below code in your css for carousel-caption

```css
.carousel-caption {
  position: absolute;
  right: 15%;
  top: 45%; // this will help in placing the content in middle vertically
  left: 15%;
  z-index: 10;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
```